# Spring Websocket convertAndSendToUser doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I successfully subscribe to a queue, but when sending a message, another user does not receive it

message broker configuration:

```
override fun configureMessageBroker(config: MessageBrokerRegistry) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic")
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
}
```

How i send message

```
messageTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(recipientId.toString(), "/queue/chat", message)
```

Creating custom user principal on ws connection

```
override fun preSend(message: Message<*>, channel: MessageChannel): Message<*>? {
            val accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor::class.java)
            if (accessor != null && StompCommand.CONNECT == accessor.command) {
                val customPrincipal = CustomPrincipal(userId)
                val authentication = CustomAuthToken(customPrincipal, roles)
                accessor.user = authentication
                return MessageBuilder.createMessage(message.payload, accessor.messageHeaders)
            }
            return message
        }
    }
```

On client side i connect socket

```
this.stompClient.connect(headers, () => {
    this.stompClient.subscribe(headers, "/user/queue/chat", (message) => {
        console.log("connected");
        console.log(message);
    });
});
```

When i connect to stomp i see in browser console next message

```
<<< CONNECTED
user-name:1
heart-beat:0,0
version:1.2
content-length:0
```

`user-name` is my actual id for this user
I subscribe user with id 1 and user with id 2 to same queue, when i send a message from user 1 to user 2 second user doesn't receive it.
Did i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

After 5 hours of debugging Spring i found how to fix this issue

Just set accessor (in `preSend` method) immutable

```
accessor.setLeaveMutable(false)
```

Still don't fully understand why this happend, would be useful if anyone could explain it
I didn't find anything in documentation about this